# How to show/hide polygon on tap of a marker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-web

I'm implementing google map in my flutter web application. I'm trying to add a feature to show and hide polygon on tap of a marker.
So what I have tried is, I declared a bool type variable and set it's value to false. Then pass that variable to visible property of polygon. But then I try to set the variable to true onTap of the marker it shows me error(The instance member '_polyShow' can't be accessed in an initializer.).
Please suggest me something.

```
        import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GooMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GooMapState createState() => _GooMapState();
}

class _GooMapState extends State<GooMap> {
  Set<Marker> _markers = HashSet<Marker>();
  Set<Polygon> _polygons = HashSet<Polygon>();
  Set<Circle> _circles = HashSet<Circle>();
  late GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  late BitmapDescriptor _markerIcon;
  late double radius;
  bool _polyShow = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _markers.addAll(list);
      _setPolygon();
    });
  }

  void _setMarkerIcon() async {
    _markerIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/farm.png');
  }

  void _setPolygon() {
    List<LatLng> polygonLatLong1 = [
      LatLng(42.90834700916708, -78.79172716139108),
      LatLng(42.90691678768724, -78.78971014021188),
      LatLng(42.907828361256655, -78.78758583067209),
      LatLng(42.908959951071324, -78.78960285185128)
    ];

    _polygons.add(
      Polygon(
          polygonId: PolygonId("1"),
          points: polygonLatLong1,
          fillColor: Colors.transparent,
          strokeWidth: 2,
          visible: _polyShow,
          strokeColor: Colors.blue),
    );
  }

  List<Marker> list = [
    Marker(
        markerId: const MarkerId('Marker1'),
        position: LatLng(32.195476, 74.2023563),
        infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'Business 1'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
        consumeTapEvents: true,
        onTap: () {
          _polyShow = true;
        }),
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('Marker2'),
      position: LatLng(31.110484, 72.384598),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Business 2'),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
    )
  ];

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _googleMapController = controller;
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('1'),
          position: LatLng(42.907645, -78.790063),
          icon: _markerIcon,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(42.907645, -78.790063),
                zoom: 16,
              ),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(list),
              circles: _circles,
              polygons: _polygons,
              myLocationEnabled: true,),],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store your LatLng, when you need, then build polygons to your _polygons set and when you want to hide them, just empty the _polygons set